# How do I shut off the DataNucleus byte code enhancer?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans, datanucleus

For the Eclipse App Engine plugin, the answer is easy - go to the Project Properties -> Builders and disable the Enhancer. Is there a way to do the same in NetBeans (using the NetBeans IDE plugin for Google App Engine), to reduce the build time for projects which do not need DataNucleus?

Comment: You presumably enabled it in your Ant build.xml in the first place, so I would have thought that's the place to disable it ;-)

Comment: @DataNucleus the NetBeans build.xml (and referenced build-impl.xml) contains no references to app engine or datanucleus. I am using the nbappengine plugin, maybe it is hidden inside there

Comment: Ahh, ok. Missed the GAE aspect of your question. Never used that plugin so no idea.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want the enhancer disabled?

Comment: @Dave it would speed up the build process a little